# How to solve jpa Invalid resource

Tags: jpa, glassfish

I am using jpa as database connection method. The database I am using is Derby. But I always got below error when deploy on glassfish server.

```
Severe:   Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : java:app/UserDemoDB__pm
```

I know that the error is about the resource jndi name but I don't know how to set it correctly. 
Below is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="UserDemoPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:app/UserDemoDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>homesoft.userdemo.entities.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Below is my glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Resource Definitions//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd">
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="derby_net_UserDemoDB_appPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="1527"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="UserDemoDB"/>
        <property name="User" value="app"/>
        <property name="Password" value="app"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/UserDemoDB"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="java:app/UserDemoDB" object-type="user" pool-name="derby_net_UserDemoDB_appPool"/>
</resources>
```

what else should I configure for using jndi resource.

Comment: What is the UserDemoDB__pm resource?  You've defined a persistence-unit name of "UserDemoPU", so there is no indication of where the UserDemoDB__pm is coming from.

Comment: right, I didn't define UserDemoDB_pm so I don't know where it comes from. BTW, I am using netbeans as IDE is there any setting need to be updated?